# How do I display the files being accessed by a recursive search in the WinForm UI?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, user-interface, event-handling, backgroundworker

I have written a program that recursively go through a directory, chosen through a folder browser dialog, and makes an inventory of all the files in it and all sub directories. For each file, I create a file object and give it the properties of name, path and created date. Then I add them to a object list to be sorted and printed as a csv. I have now been asked to add the ability to watch the search in the UI, in place of something like a progress bar.

I am very new to writing WinForm UIs, so I'm not entirely sure where to begin. I have been going down the road of updating the toolstripstatuslabel for each file object created, but am not sure how that should be done. I have read suggestions to use BackgroundWorker for similar tasks, but as this is the only task this program does, it seems a bit like overkill. I am thinking I need to use an eventhandler/delegate, but an not entirely sure how to implement it.

I'm glad to post any code that would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want a list of all files accessed, or just to see the one currently being accessed?

Comment: Just the one currently being accessed. Each one will flash up for only a moment, but it will be indicative of progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to achieve this by adding a event handler to the class that contained the recursive search. When I set the name of the file object for each file in the directories, set an onPropertyChanged event. I tied that to the form in the DoWork of my background worker. Then I reported progress when the event was triggered and used the background worker ProgressChanged to set the text to the current file name. Here are some code snippets from my program to help anybody trying to something similar.

*In the searching class*

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
    {
       //creating objects for each file in the directory
       FileObject fileObject = new FileObject();
       FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
       currentfile = file.ToString();
       fileObject.name = info.Name.ToString();
       fileObject.path = file.ToString();
       fileObject.createdDate = info.CreationTime.ToString();
       FileList.Add(fileObject);
       //event handler triggered
       OnFileNameChanged(name);
    }

//event handler code
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnFileNameChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

*In the windows form*

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
       //do some work
      search.PropertyChanged += (s, pe) => backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(unusedNumber);
      backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100);
    }
 private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      //change label
      label1.Text = search.currentfile;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use event as a solution if you don't want the UI to be "clickable". Recursive code   should provide an event and your UI can subscribe it. Event handler will get neccessary data and redraw the form. But usually it's not good approach. You will not be able to act with your form cause the UI thread is busy with the task and you cannot abort you task in a user-friendly manner (without killing it's process).

Comment: What is approach would you suggest then? BackgroundWorker?

Comment: Yes. It will be the best here to start and fill what you need to build proper user-friendly Win app.